# How do I install amd legacy drivers in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I am new to Ubuntu and would like to know how I can install amd graphic drivers?
Also do I need to manually uninstall the open-source drivers in use right now?

Comment: Hi welcome to askubuntu. Do you really need to install the proprietary drivers because you are noticing performance issues or such? Since you want to install the legacy drivers I am assuming you have an older ATI card which should be working pretty good with the community drivers already installed. Especially with amd drivers I would go with the policy: "never touch a running system" :P But if you want to change it I will post an answer with the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a pretty straight forward graphical way to do this.
Open your system settings and click on `Software & Updates`

There it should list some available drivers that have been detected for your System.
Just select the one you want, install it and reboot your system.

***EDIT***
According to AMD and this bug report: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1058040
your card is not supported by the regular amd drivers anymore. 
It is, according to AMDs download page, not possible to use the legacy drivers with linux kernel verisons higher than 3.4 (as of Ubuntu 12.04.2 kernel > 3.5.x is in use). 
See description section on the official AMD download site: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

In other words: You can not use an official AMD driver for your card.
Your options are:

1. Leave your system as it is and use the default `radeon` drivers already in use on your system (recommended!)
2. Get a newer card (HD 5xxx and above) and install the official drivers via terminal 
   `sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle`
3. Reinstall your system to a version prior to Ubuntu 12.04.2 and install the amd legacy drivers from the link provided above (SERIOUSLY NOT RECOMMENDED! ..just to be complete)

Comment: Hi i try this method but i dont have nothing in "additional drivers" ;/ i have ati HD 4***

Comment: I just edited my answer to include some new information I just found. Doesn't look too good for you though...In short: you can't use the legacy drivers in 13.10